# Hide payment method if company name field got a value

Tags: customer, payment, payment-methods

I want to auto change the assigned group to business, if a customer enters the field "Company name" in the checkout.

I want to hide a payment method, if a customer enters the field "Company name" in the checkout.

This so that a payment method is not possible for business customers.

How can I achieve that?

Payment form:

```
<?php $this->setBlockData()?>
<?php $_code = $this->getMethodCode(); ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('afterpay');?>
<?php $isEnterprise = (bool) Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig("Enterprise_Enterprise")->version;?>

<div id="payment-errors" class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>

<fieldset class="form-list">
    <ul id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code; ?>" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <?php if($this->country == 'dede') : ?>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_gender" class = "required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Gender:'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box" id="">
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="M" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m" checked="checked">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m"><?php echo $_helper->__('Male'); ?></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="V" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v"><?php echo $_helper->__('Female'); ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_gender" class = "required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Gender:'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box" id="">
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="M" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m" checked="checked">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m"><?php echo $_helper->__('Male'); ?></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="V" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v"><?php echo $_helper->__('Female'); ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($isEnterprise): ?>
            </li>
            <li>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if (!$this->isB2B()): ?>
            <div class="field">
                <?php 
                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('afterpay/customer_widget_dob')
                                       ->setFieldIdFormat($_code . ':billing:%s')
                                       ->setFieldNameFormat('payment[' . $_code . '][%s]')
                                       ->setIsRequired(true)
                                       ->setPaymentMethodCode($_code)
                                       ->toHtml() 
                ?>
             </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($this->showBankaccount()): ?>
            <li> 
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_bankaccount" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Bank account number:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_bankaccount" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][bankaccount]" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isB2B()): ?>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_companyname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Company name:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getCompany(); ?>" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_companyname" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][companyname]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_department" class=""><?php echo $_helper->__('Department:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_department" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][department]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_coc" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Coc number:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_coc" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][coc]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_vat" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Vatnumber:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_vat" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][vat]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_costcenter"><?php echo $_helper->__('Costcenter'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_costcenter" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][costcenter]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li> 
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="payment.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php if (!$this->isAdvisoryprocess() && $this->country != 'dede'): ?>
        <li class="accept-afterpay">
            <input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][conditions]"  style="float:left;">
            <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" class="required" style="padding-left:5px; float:left;">
                <em>*</em>
                <?php echo $_helper->__(
                    'Ik ga akkoord met de %sbetalingsvoorwaarden%s van AfterPay',
                    $this->paymentConditionsUrl,
                    $this->anchorClose
                );?>
            </label>
        </li>
        <?php elseif ($this->isAdvisoryprocess() && $this->country != 'dede'): ?>
        <li class="accept-afterpay">
            <input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][conditions]"  style="float:left;">
            <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" class="required" style="padding-left:5px; float:left;">
                <em>*</em>
                <?php echo $_helper->__(
                    'Ik ga akkoord met de %sbetalingsvoorwaarden%s van Mijnbetaalplan',
                    $this->paymentConditionsUrl,
                    $this->anchorClose
                );?>
            </label>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: need to hide all payment methods?

Comment: can share your payment method code & name?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to bellow code:

```
<?php $this->setBlockData()?>
<?php $_code = $this->getMethodCode(); ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('afterpay');?>
<?php $isEnterprise = (bool) Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig("Enterprise_Enterprise")->version;?>
<?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();?>
<?php $address = $quote->getBillingAddress();?>

<div id="payment-errors" class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
<?php if($address->getCompany()):?>
<?php else :?>
<fieldset class="form-list">
    <ul id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code; ?>" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <?php if($this->country == 'dede') : ?>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_gender" class = "required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Gender:'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box" id="">
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="M" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m" checked="checked">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m"><?php echo $_helper->__('Male'); ?></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="V" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v"><?php echo $_helper->__('Female'); ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_gender" class = "required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Gender:'); ?></label>
                <div class="input-box" id="">
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="M" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m" checked="checked">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_m"><?php echo $_helper->__('Male'); ?></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][gender]" value="V" id="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v">
                    <label style="float:none" for="<?php echo $_code?>_gender_v"><?php echo $_helper->__('Female'); ?></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($isEnterprise): ?>
            </li>
            <li>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if (!$this->isB2B()): ?>
            <div class="field">
                <?php 
                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('afterpay/customer_widget_dob')
                                       ->setFieldIdFormat($_code . ':billing:%s')
                                       ->setFieldNameFormat('payment[' . $_code . '][%s]')
                                       ->setIsRequired(true)
                                       ->setPaymentMethodCode($_code)
                                       ->toHtml() 
                ?>
             </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($this->showBankaccount()): ?>
            <li> 
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_bankaccount" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Bank account number:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_bankaccount" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][bankaccount]" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isB2B()): ?>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_companyname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Company name:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getCompany(); ?>" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_companyname" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][companyname]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_department" class=""><?php echo $_helper->__('Department:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_department" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][department]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_coc" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Coc number:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_coc" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][coc]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_vat" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_helper->__('Vatnumber:'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class = "required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_vat" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][vat]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_costcenter"><?php echo $_helper->__('Costcenter'); ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_costcenter" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][costcenter]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li> 
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="payment.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php if (!$this->isAdvisoryprocess() && $this->country != 'dede'): ?>
        <li class="accept-afterpay">
            <input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][conditions]"  style="float:left;">
            <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" class="required" style="padding-left:5px; float:left;">
                <em>*</em>
                <?php echo $_helper->__(
                    'Ik ga akkoord met de %sbetalingsvoorwaarden%s van AfterPay',
                    $this->paymentConditionsUrl,
                    $this->anchorClose
                );?>
            </label>
        </li>
        <?php elseif ($this->isAdvisoryprocess() && $this->country != 'dede'): ?>
        <li class="accept-afterpay">
            <input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" id="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" name="payment[<?php echo $_code; ?>][conditions]"  style="float:left;">
            <label for="<?php echo $_code; ?>_termsAndConditions" class="required" style="padding-left:5px; float:left;">
                <em>*</em>
                <?php echo $_helper->__(
                    'Ik ga akkoord met de %sbetalingsvoorwaarden%s van Mijnbetaalplan',
                    $this->paymentConditionsUrl,
                    $this->anchorClose
                );?>
            </label>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that code, but that does not work. I use the method with codename portfolio_a. That payment method does have its own template file with <fieldset>. Is there a way to hide all the html inside that template file, when the company adress got value?

Comment: can you share your template file code???

Comment: I updated my question, with the right code. The payment code is portfolio_a.

Comment: Updated my ans pls check now :)

Comment: Thanks! But I made a mistake. In that case the payment method is still displayed, but i can not click on it. So I need the modify the payment/methods.phtml file. My payment code is portfolio_a. How do I need to edit the methods.pthml file?

Comment: Do you know how to update the code, to make it work with the payment/methods.phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observer for the event `payment_method_is_active`.
Something like this:

```
public function checkPaymentMethodActive($observer)
{
    $methodInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
    if ($methodInstance->getCode() == 'your payment method code here') {
        $billingAddress = $this->getEvent()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
        if ($billingAddress->getCompany()) {
             $result = $this->getEvent()->getResult();  
             $result->isAvailable = false;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where do I need tho place that code?

Comment: you can see here some explanations on how to create an observer: https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Using+the+Event-Observer+Method+in+Magento+1.x .If that's not enough, you can search the web for a way to create an observer.