# Magento 2: Hide payment method if company name field got a value

Tags: magento2, checkout

Hi i'm trying to hide a payment method if the company field is filled. I did find a solution but it's for Magento 1 (see link below). Does anyone know how i would do this in Magento 2? I'm working in Magento 2.3.4 if that's relevant.

M1 solution: [Hide payment method if company name field got a value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98495/hide-payment-method-if-company-name-field-got-a-value)

If i look on stackexchange there are some solutions for hiding a payment method ([Magento 2: Hide payment methods depends on shipping method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192405/magento-2-hide-payment-methods-depends-on-shipping-method)) but i'm not sure how to get the company name data in there?

Comment: which company field? in shipping  form or another

Answer (score 0):

create below files in your custom module.

The below example is used to hide the `cash on delivery payment method`

You can create an observer for the event `payment_method_is_active`

> **Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **Vendor/Module/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $cart;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    Cart $cart,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
  ){
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    //shipping company field
    $shippingCompanyField = $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCompany();

    //Billing company field
    $billingCompanyField = $this->cart->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCompany();

    $paymentMethod = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

    if ($shippingCompanyField != '') {
      if ($paymentMethod == "cashondelivery") {
        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
    }
    }

}
}
```

I just check shippingCompanyField is filled or not. you can also check the billing company field then you can check another condition.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It works but, if i got to the checkout and add company and go to payment so the field is there. And then go back a step and remove company so the field is gone but it was already selected then payment provider crashes because the selected method is gone now. Any idea? I tried googling on deselecting payment methods but no results.